# The userPrincipleName returns via Graph API is unavailable

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

According to the document[1], we can user Graph API to get all of the office 365 user information, included their userPrincipalName (UPN).

However, one of the user's userPrincipalName can't be used in both Graph and EWS API.
The server always returns 'ResourceNotFound' from Graph API, and returns 'ErrorInvalidUserPrincipalName' from EWS API.

There are detail response and response.
Noticed, the userPrincipalName I used is got from Graph API: `GET /users`.

Case 1. Failed to get calendar[2] with the userPrincipalName but success with user's id via Graph API.

Here are the request and response with userPrincipalName.

Request: `GET /users/{userPrincipalName}/calendars`

Response:

```
{ 
    "error": { 
        "code": "ResourceNotFound", 
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.", 
        "innerError": { 
            "request-id": "b3587019-1d8c-41ed-89e7-4a3e868b8933", 
            "date": "2019-07-23T05:57:08" 
        } 
    }
}
```

Case 2. Failed to get calendar folder with userPrincipalName but success with PrimarySmtpAddress (email) via EWS API.

Here are the request and response with userPrincipalName.

Request: as detailed in [3]

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types>a:ErrorInvalidUserPrincipalName</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The impersonation principal name is invalid.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorInvalidUserPrincipalName</e:ResponseCode>
                <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The impersonation principal name is invalid.</e:Message>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

It seems that there are some problems so that the server can't recognize this userPrincipalName.
However, I need a correct userPrincipalName to send EWS API.
What can I do?
Thanks.

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
[3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getfolder-operation

Comment: May I know if the user was assigned with any available O365 license? If no license was assigned, he will not be able to use the mail, neither the calendar.  If the user was just assigned with the license for a few minutes, you can wait for a while.

Comment: @JackJia The user has an available O365 license and I can get his calendar list via Graph API with the user id. However, it failed to get calendar list if I use the userPrincipleName with Graph API. It seems that the server can't recognize the userPrincipleName but I need use it to connect with EWS API.